# Can someone confirm this PHP cron job will run once a month on the 1st at 3am?

Tags: php, cron

```
0 3 1 * * /var/www/crons/monthly_billing.php 2>&1
```

Also anyone see any problems with it?

Comment: might put   /usr/bin/php   or whatever the path to php is on your system just to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man 5 crontab` says... yes. Looks good. The only problem may be if the script is not set executable or is missing the shebang line.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to add the path to where php is running

```
0 3 1 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/crons/monthly_billing.php 2>&1
```

Also where are you planning on sending the output result to the users local email address (e.g. jbloggs@localhost) which it would be doing at the moment or are you after redirecting it, into a log file.

NOTE: dont copy paste the example i have given here you might need to confirm the location of where the php binary file is on your server `which php` is your friend for this.

Answer (score 1):

Also, following on Pauls notation regarding output result. If you don't want any output (discard all output, both stdout and stderr) try:

> 0 3 1 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/crons/monthly_billing.php >> /dev/null 2>&1